# How iterate over recursive hash containing nested same structured array of objects

Tags: ruby

Suppose we have the following object:

```
foo = {
  a: '1.0',
  children: [
    {
      a: '1.1',
      children: [
        {
          a: '1.1.1',
          children: []
        },
        {
          a: '1.1.2',
          children: [
            { a: '1.1.2.1' , children: [] }
          ]
        },
        {
          a: 1.2,
          children: [
            {
              a: '1.2.1',
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a link to repl: https://repl.it/repls/ForkedThistleObjectmodel. The task is to recursively iterate over all children objects and print a value for the `a` key. Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected result? What have you tried? What stopped you?

Comment: Write a recursive method and start digging. Hint: `each`.

Comment: Yeah. I wanted to eliminate recursive function. It seems this is only solution. Going to add an answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is only recursive version which looks something like this:

```
def step(obj, level = 0)
  p "Current: level - #{level}; a: #{obj[:a]}"

  obj[:children].each do |item|
    step(item, level + 1)
  end
end

step(foo)
```

Here is [a repl link](https://repl.it/repls/ForkedThistleObjectmodel)

Answer (score 0):

Like the other posters have mentioned, what do you expect for output? If you want something like this:

```
a=>1.0
a=>1.1
a=>1.1.1
a=>1.1.2
a=>1.1.2.1
a=>1.2
a=>1.2.1
```

To print the values to standard out then you could try two recursive functions.

```
def display_foo_aux(f)
  f.each{|e|
    display_foo(e)
  }
end

def display_foo(f)

  f.each{|k, v| 
    if k == :children
      display_foo_aux(v)
    else
      puts "#{k}=>#{v}"
    end
  }

end

display_foo(foo)
```

If you need to produce a list of values then you need to accumulate the elements.